# How to get an object's id and use it for child's query?

Tags: django

```
def customer(request, customer_id):
     """Displays customer profile"""
     customer = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
     entries = customer.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
     subentry = SubEntry.objects.get()
     context = {'customer': customer, 'entries': entries, 'subentry': subentry}
     return render(request, 'crm/customer.html', context)
```

I have three classes, Customer, Entry and SubEntry. Customer is a ForeignKey to Entry and Entry is a ForeignKey to SubEntry. Each class has a textfield whose id I can access through the python shell. Currently, I have customer.html displaying a loop that iterates through the `entries` for a `customer`, but one `subentry` prints on all `entries` instead of printing the correct unique text. Is there are better way to show this information and print out the `subentry` for each entry?

The snippet below is an example of how each class looks like:

```py
class SubEntry(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Subentries'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subentry
```

This is how I attempted to solve the issue:

```py
def customer(request, customer_id, entry_id):     
"""Displays cx profile"""     
customer = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)     
entries = customer.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')     unique_entry_id = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)     
subentry = SubEntry.objects.get(unique_entry_id)     
context = {'customer': customer, 'entries': entries, 'subentry': subentry,}     
return render(request, 'crm/customer.html', context)
```

This revised code threw out a TypeError: customer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entry_id'.

Comment: What do the Customer, Entry, and SubEntry models look like? That will affect what ORM code is used to do this.

Comment: Share what you have done so far to address this issue.